# How do I add a for loop to a class file function?

Tags: sectioning, xetex, loops

I'm using this XeLaTeX [class](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv/blob/master/friggeri-cv.cls) file to write my resume. One of the features is for section headings it colors the first 3 letters:

```
\section{experience}
```

This is hardcoded to the first 3 letters, and I'd like to make it a variable length:

```
\section{4}{open source}
```

I modified the `\section` part as follows:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Structure %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[2]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1#2%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{
  \par\vspace{1\parskip}%
  \Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2%
  \par\vspace{1.25\parskip}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

I'm not sure how to modify the section part with a for loop and color only a certain number of characters.

Comment: Is the first 3 letters all the same colour for one section, and then a different colour for the next section, and so on? You want this pattern to still be the same, but just have you be able to modify the number of characters to be coloured, right?

Comment: With `\section{5}{The title}` what characters should be colored?

Comment: @Werner: Yes, the first 3 letters of a section are the same color but the next section uses a different color. @egreg: With `\section{5}{The title}` example, "`The t`itle" would be colored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to provide a suggestion using `expl3`:

First of all I used the `expl3` syntax to define an approach.

The problem was the space inside the title. color-command: `\frigger_sectioncolor:` It is the same as yours ;-)

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \frigger_sectioncolor:
 {
 \prg_case_int:nnn {  \value{colorCounter}  }
  {
   { 0 } { \color{blue} }
   { 1 } { \color{red} }
   { 2 } { \color{orange} }
   { 3 } { \color{green} }
   { 4 } { \color{purple} }
  }
  {  \color{headercolor} }
 }
```

If you want to restart the coloring after the usage of `\color{headcolor}` you can use the definition:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \frigger_sectioncolor:
 {
 \prg_case_int:nnn {  \value{colorCounter}  }
  {
   { 0 } { \color{blue} }
   { 1 } { \color{red} }
   { 2 } { \color{orange} }
   { 3 } { \color{green} }
   { 4 } { \color{purple} }
  }
  {  
    \color{headercolor}
    \int_gset:Nn \c@colorCounter { 0 }
  }
 }
```

In the next step I declared the command `\section` with two mandatory arguments.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \section { m m }
{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 0 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } {\nil}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn  \l_tmpa_tl 
      {
      \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \nil }
             {~}
            {
              \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int  } < { #1 } 
                 {
                   \group_begin:
                           \frigger_sectioncolor: ##1 
                   \group_end:
                 }
                {
                   ##1 
                }
              }
           \int_gincr:N  \l_tmpa_int 
       }
    \int_gincr:N \c@colorCounter
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}
```

This step was necessary to handle spacing when using `\tl_map_inline:Nn`.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } {\nil}
```

The complete MWE and the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{frigger-cv}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \frigger_sectioncolor:
 {
 \prg_case_int:nnn {  \value{colorCounter}  }
  {
   { 0 } { \color{blue} }
   { 1 } { \color{red} }
   { 2 } { \color{orange} }
   { 3 } { \color{green} }
   { 4 } { \color{purple} }
  }
  {  \color{headercolor} }
 }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \section { m m }
{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 0 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } {\nil}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn  \l_tmpa_tl 
      {
      \str_if_eq:nnTF { ##1 } { \nil }
             {~}
            {
              \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int  } < { #1 } 
                 {
                   \group_begin:
                           \frigger_sectioncolor: ##1 
                   \group_end:
                 }
                {
                   ##1 
                }
              }
           \int_gincr:N  \l_tmpa_int 
       }
    \int_gincr:N \c@colorCounter
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{6}{open source}

\section{3}{The Title}

\section{2}{open source}

\section{5}{The Title}


\kant[1]
\end{document}
```